# Removing items in a loop and adding a new array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to add data into a new array and remove data from the current list on a button click. Right now it only removes the last item and sometimes two checked items not 4-6 items.

```
$scope.LoadBack = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.MyArrold.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.MyArrold[i].checked == true) { 
      $scope.BackList.push(angular.extend({}, $scope.MyArrold[i]));            
      var index = $scope.MyArrold.indexOf($scope.MyArrold[i]);
      $scope.MyArrold.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just add i--; after you splice the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're removing items from the array while you are in a loop which is iterating over the array. That doesn't work.

One way to solve this is to add the items you want to keep to a temp array and then assign that array back to MyArrold after the loop completes.

Another way to solve this is to track the indexes you wish to remove in a temp array, and then iterate over this array after the loop completes, backwards! To use this solution you have to iterate backwards else all future indexes become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = $scope.MyArrold.length;
while (i--) {
   if ($scope.MyArrold[i].checked === true) {          
      $scope.MyArrold.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```